# JSON/XML parsing iphone NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, xml, json, parsing, nspredicate

I'm trying to create a little apps which use xml or json to display some content.

I'have a lot of "views" and i want to select just one from her id.

XML look like that (i can put json if you want but it's very hard to read) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<views>
    <view id="home" type="nav">
        <title>Help</title>
        <section id="1">
        <title>Aide</title>
        <item id="1" link="dev_mac">Dev Mac</item>
        <item id="2" link="dev_iphone">Dev iPhone</item>
        <item id="3" link="examples">Examples</item>
        </section>
    </view>
    <view id="dev_mac" type="nav">
        <nav_title>Help</nav_title>
        <content_title>Dev Mac</content_title>
        <text>balbalbalblablablalbalblalbal</text>
        <section id="1">
        <item id="1" link="lesson_1">Lesson 1</item>
        <item id="2" link="download">Downlaod</item>
        </section>
    </view>
    <view id="download" type="content">
        <nav_title>Dev Mac</nav_title>
        <title>Lesson 1</title>
        <content_text>balblablalbalblalbalb</content_text>
        <content_title>A. UIKit</content_title>
        <content_text>UIKit is .....</content_text>
    </view>
</views>
```

I have an array which contain 3 NSDictionary (the 3 view).

How can i select juste one view by her id ?

Thanks by advance

BiB1

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `NSPredicate` on XML directly.  You'll have to parse the XML (or JSON) into some standard Cocoa container (`NSArray`, etc) and then use it on that.

The only way you'd be able to filter the XML directly is to use something like XPath, though you'd have to drop to libxml to do that.

Comment: Yes i know, i don't want to use NSPredicate directly on XML. My XML data is converted into NSDictionary with XMLReader. but i don't find how to use NSPredicate to select "parent item" from is id in my NSDictionary (or NSArray)

Answer (score 0):

It should work - as long as the data variable is actually an array containing a dictionary with the key "id"

```
NSArray *data =  <your xml>
NSString *currentViewId = @"home";
NSArray *filterd = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(id == %@)", currentViewId]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reformatting the xml as a plist (you could use xcodes plist editor or roll your own) use:

```
<plist version="1.0">
 <array>
    <dict>
        <key>Title</key><string>Home</string>
        <key>Image</key><string>Home.png</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Title</key><string>Car</string>
        <key>Image</key><string>Car.png</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist
```

In .h file:

```
NSArray *Views_List;
```

In .m file:

```
   NSString *Views_DataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nameOfYourPlist" ofType:@"plist"];   
    Views_List = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:Views_DataPath];
```

then to access each dict:

```
[[Views_List objectAtIndex: 0] valueForKey:@"Title"];
```

In this example (0) will return 'Home'

Comment: unluckily i can't use objectAtIndex in case of views are sent in a different order